# How can I find the service UUID of my Mulitmeter

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am trying to connect my Bluetooth Multimeter to my Android device but for that I have to find out the Service UUID, the Read characteristic UUID and the Write Characteristic UUID. The Mulitmeter is an owon ow18b bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be accomplished by using a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile).

Scan for all BLE devices around you and find your Multimeter. If you can't identify it by name try to rule out the other devices until there is only one left. Connect to it and the app will show you all services and characteristics available.